# Implicitly disabling animations in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing an application in WPF and .Net 4 which contains animations.

My controls are bound to certain values in the business logic, which toggles animations under certain conditions. The problem I am encountering is that those animations may play as soon as the application launches, which makes controls "animate" toward their initial state when first displayed.

Let's say for example that I am developing the Login portion of the application. I have a control that represents a custom popup which should appear above the username and password fields if these are invalid. When the application launches, both those fields are invalid by default which prompts the popups to be displayed through an animation. I would like to prevent these animations from playing at start-up, without disabling them explicitly.

Another example to demonstrate my problem would be a toggle button bound to a boolean Property. If I saved the state of the button as being toggled prior to closing the application, the button would "animate" towards the toggled state when the application re-launches (since I have an animation between toggled states), instead of simply being toggled on without animating.

Is there a way to temporarily disable all animations from playing ?

I read somewhere that the best way to disable an animation is to call SkipToFill(...) on a particular Storyboard. The problem with that is that I have to explicitly disable all animations concerned, which may be a problem if these are not known beforehand.

```
Storyboard theBoard = (Storyboard)FindResource(resourceName); 
theBoard.Begin(this, true); 
theBoard.SkipToFill(this);
```

How would you go about disabling animations without explicitly disabling them one by one ? Is such a thing even possible ?

Comment: The problem isn't your view, but the logic which triggers the view displaying the username and password is invalid. When do you check whether they are valid?

Comment: I have two boolean properties, UsernameIsValid and PasswordIsValid, which default to false. A field is valid in the event that it's not empty and in the case of the username, doesn't contain a special character. These conditions are checked when a user types in either fields. When both are valid, the Login button is enabled. I understand your point of view, and I thought of flagging them as valid at start-up, but I'd rather not "hack" the system.

Comment: @Hussein Khalil I believe one of the UI DP metadata options is - Animatable, so presumably you can try setting it to false, would it be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using an attached dependency property (attached on StoryBoards) that would enable or disable your animations (or set their duration to 0) ? Maybe there's a simpler solution but since none seems to be proposed, i suggest that one.
Rq : i'm not sure the controls beeing animated on window opening is a very boring thing. But i don't know, maybe if there's a lot of animation on the screen, maybe it can look strange.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. I ended up fixing this problem by rewriting my code's logic, as I couldn't find a better solution back when I posted this question. Using an attached dependency property might have solved the problem, I might have to try it out.

Comment: well since it wasn't tested, i'm not sure my answer is an answer, but glad you could solve your issue.